# WCF use of SOAP gives error when deserializing response defined in WSDL as empty message

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm very new to WCF and the related technologies. (Using WCF 4.0, by the way.)

Here are some snippets from the WSDL file for a web service that I need to interface with.

```
  <wsdl:binding name="MPGWCSTAOperations_v1_1SoapBinding" type="impl:MPGWCSTAOperations">
    <wsdlsoap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    ...
    <wsdl:operation name="MonitorStartLine">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="urn:v1_1.csta.ws.mpgw.gintel.com/MonitorStart" />
      <wsdl:input name="MonitorStartLineRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="MonitorStartLineResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    ...
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:portType name="MPGWCSTAOperations">
  ...
    <wsdl:operation name="MonitorStartLine" parameterOrder="monitorStartLine">
      <wsdl:input name="MonitorStartLineRequest" message="impl:MonitorStartLineRequest" />
      <wsdl:output name="MonitorStartLineResponse" message="impl:MonitorStartLineResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    ....
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:message name="MonitorStartLineResponse" />
```

My understanding is that the MonitorStartLine operation is defined to return a response message MonitorStartLineResponse, which is defined to be an empty message.

I've used Visual Studio's Project - Add Service Reference facility to generate C# proxy code for this.

Then I do something like this:

```
   MPGWCSTAOperationsClient cstaOperationsClient = new MPGWCSTAOperationsClient();

   MonitorStartLine monitorStartLine = new MonitorStartLine();
   monitorStartLine.pnis = new string[] {"0000032"};

   cstaOperationsClient.MonitorStartLine(monitorStartLine);
```

This results in the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'MonitorStartLine'. 
  End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. 
  Found element 'monitorStartLineResponse' from namespace 'urn:v1_1.csta.ws.mpgw.gintel.com'. Line 1, position 296.
  Source=mscorlib
```

Using Fiddler I'm seeing the response as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 16 Oct 2013 22:01:44 GMT

149
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <monitorStartLineResponse xmlns="urn:v1_1.csta.ws.mpgw.gintel.com"/>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Which looks to me like it conforms to the WSDL.

I'm thinking that I can probably just ignore the error (the server will never be the wiser), but I'd prefer to fix the problem if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the workaround that I implemented. (It is debatable as to whether it's better to implement a workaround or to just ignore the exception - I prefer to do it this way.)

What I'm doing is modifying the response message before WCF invokes SOAP processing on it. I'm simply removing the XML element that WCF/SOAP don't think should be there.

```
   /// <summary>
   /// This class is used to provide a workaround for a problem due to the (censored) server sending 
   /// responses encoded in SOAP which do not, at least according to WCF standards, conform to the 
   /// WSDL specifications published for the server. 
   /// </summary>
   public class MessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
   {
      public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message requestMessage, IClientChannel clientChannel)
      {
         return null;  // Method not needed
      }


      public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message replyMessage, object correlationState)
      {
         if (replyMessage.IsFault)
            return;  // Avoid distortion of SOAP fault messages

         string messageBody;

         using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
         {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream))
            {
               replyMessage.WriteMessage(xmlWriter);
               xmlWriter.Flush();
               messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
         }

         messageBody = messageBody.Replace(
                     "<monitorStartLineResponse xmlns=\"urn:v1_1.csta.ws.mpgw.gintel.com\" />", "");

         using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody)))
         {
            using (XmlDictionaryReader xmlDictionaryReader = 
                XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(memoryStream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()))
            {
               Message newMessage = 
                     Message.CreateMessage(xmlDictionaryReader, int.MaxValue, replyMessage.Version);
               newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(replyMessage.Properties);
               replyMessage = newMessage;
            }
         }
      }
   }


   /// <summary>
   /// Class needed to inject the above MessageInspector class into the WCF processing of messages.
   /// </summary>
   public class InjectInspectorBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
   {
      public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint)
      {
         // Method not needed
      }

      public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, 
                                       BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
      {
         // Method not needed
      }

      public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, 
                                        EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
      {
         // Method not needed
      }

      public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
      {
         clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MessageInspector());
      }
   }
```

This is put into operation by adding the second line shown here:

```
  _cstaOperationsClient = new MPGWCSTAOperationsClient();
  _cstaOperationsClient.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new InjectInspectorBehavior());
```

The above code is largely based on code found in these two locations:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2008/01/08/modify-message-content-with-wcf.aspx

[Replacing content of WCF Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286309/replacing-content-of-wcf-message)

Comment: +1 but I would use LINQ to XML to remove the offending element. In general, it's a bad idea to use string manipulation to process XML.

Answer (score 4):

The message conforms to the WSDL, but in a place where the WSDL specification is ambiguous. .NET is expecting nothing within the `Body` element, because no message parts were defined. The sender is sending an empty `monitorStartLineResponse` element instead, as though a single message part were specified, with an element named `monitorStartLineResponse`.

Because of areas where the WSDL specification is ambiguous, the [Web Services Interoperability Organization](http://www.ws-i.org/) was formed. The [WS-I Basic Profile 1.1](http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html) specification was developed to specify a subset of WSDL which is guaranteed to be interoperable across platforms.

This WSDL does not conform to WS-I BP 1.1.

---

In fact, from reading the [WSDL 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap%3aoperation) ([section 3.4, soap:operation](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap%3aoperation)), I see that this will be taken to be a "document-literal binding" because there are no "style" attributes saying otherwise.

In section [4.4.1, Bindings and Parts](http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html#Bindings_and_Parts), R2213, the WS-I BP 1.1 spec says:

> **R2213** In a doc-literal description where the value of the parts attribute of `soapbind:body` is an empty string, the corresponding ENVELOPE MUST have no element content in the `soap:Body` element.

That is what .NET is expecting, but it's not what .NET is receiving.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have no control or influence over this web service. Do you have any suggestion on how I can avoid the exception?

Comment: Yes. Refuse to use it because it does not conform to WS-I BP 1.1. I don't know if it's possible to tell WCF to ignore the meaning of the WSDL. Alternatively, I suppose you could create a hacked version of the WSDL that matches what comes on the wire.

Comment: John, thank you very much for all the authoritative information, I really appreciate it, being very new to WCF and WSDL, etc. I have upvoted your answer. Unfortunately, your "refuse to use it" advice isn't a viable option for me. So rather than just ignore the exception I've created a workaround, where I remove the offending XML element from the response before WCF processes it with SOAP. Thanks again.

Comment: Your workaround is even better than creating a hacked WSDL. You should accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's helping me see a light at the end of the tunnel :D